# UnmarshalJSON any type from []interface{} possible?

Tags: json, go, reflection, types

When you unmarshal JSON to `[]interface{}` is there any way to automatically detect the type besides some standard types like bool, int and string?

What I noticed is the following, Let's say I marshal [`[uuid.UUID, bool]`](https://github.com/satori/go.uuid) then the JSON I get looks like:

```
[[234,50,7,116,194,41,64,225,177,151,60,195,60,45,123,106],true]
```

When I unmarshal it again, I get the types as shown through `reflect`:

`[]interface{}, bool`

I don't understand why it picked `[]interface{}`. If it cannot detect it, shouldn't it be at least `interface{}`?

In any case, my question is, is it possible to unmarshal any type when the target is of type `[]interface{}`? It seems to work for standard types like string, bool, int but for custom types I don't think that's possible, is it? You can define custom JSON marshal/unmarshal methods but that only works if you decode it into a target type so that it can look up which custom marshal/unmarshal methods to use.

Answer (score 3):

You can unmarshal any type into a value of type `interface{}`. If you use a value of type `[]interface{}`, you can only unmarshal JSON arrays into it, but yes, the elements of the array may be of any type.

Since you're using `interface{}` or `[]interface{}`, yes, type information is not available, and it's up to the [`encoding/json`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/) package to choose the best it sees fit. For example, for JSON objects it will choose `map[string]interface{}`. The full list of default types is documented in [`json.Unmarshal()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal):

> To unmarshal JSON into an interface value, Unmarshal stores one of these in the interface value:
>
> ```
> bool, for JSON booleans
> float64, for JSON numbers
> string, for JSON strings
> []interface{}, for JSON arrays
> map[string]interface{}, for JSON objects
> nil for JSON null
> ```

Obviously if your JSON marshaling/unmarshaling logic needs some pre- / postprocessing, the `json` package will not miraculously find it out. It can know about those only if you unmarshal into values of specific types (which implement [`json.Unmarshaler`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshaler)). The `json` package will still be able to unmarshal them to the default types, but custom logic will obviously not run on them.